# Mercurial: Pull changes from remote repository without public phase (non-publishing server, "abort: can't rebase immutable changeset")

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-queue, mercurial-extension, mercurial-phases

### Background

Mercurial now has [Phases](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Phases) which are a great mechanism to keep people from altering history that should not be altered. When a changeset is pushed to remote repository it is made `public` and can no longer be [`rebased`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RebaseExtension). This is normally a good thing, if the repository is public and you don't want others altering your changesets.

However, if you have your own temporary repository for sharing `draft` changesets only with yourself, it can get very annoying. [Mercurial has a option to turn this off](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Phases#Publishing_Repository). Adding this to the `.hg/hgrc` file *of the remote repository*.

```
[phases]
publish = False
```

This will prevent changesets pushed to the remote repository from moving from `draft` phase to `public` phase (both the local changeset and the one just pushed to the remote repository. However, pulling this changeset down still will always pulls it down in the `public` phase.

### Question

I am hoping to pull down changesets in the `draft` phase. I simply want to push a changeset to my personal server then pull it down at home. After I pull it I will [`rebase`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RebaseExtension) my temporary commit on top of any commits that I have pulled down from our true publishing server.

Any way to avoid the auto-moving of a pulled changeset to `public` would be great. This remote repository is a complete and total draft server for myself. Being forced to manually move the changesets back to `draft` after an unsuccessful [`rebase`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RebaseExtension) attempt is really starting to wear on the nerves.

### References

- https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Phases
- [Introduction to Mercurial Phases](http://www.logilab.org/blogentry/88203)
- [How do I tell (locally) mercurial that a server is non-publishing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726360)
- [After pushing to a review repository, "abort: can't rebase immutable changeset" on rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810987)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this resolved through help on Bugzilla. Here is a snippet of [my final post there](https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3863) (thanks for putting me on the right track djc).

> It looks like we can chalk it up to User Error/Bad Test Cases (of
>   course). If there is anyone to blame (besides myself) it could be
>   TortoiseHg. My test cases consisted of stripping commits and from one
>   of the two repositories and then changing the phase of that commit in
>   the other repository and push/pull again. It seems like TortoiseHg
>   would pull in the wrong phase sometimes (possibly a caching issue). I
>   can still reproduce this when I switch my server back and forth
>   between publishing and non-publishing (but not quite as consistently
>   before).
>
> However, doing a command line pull seems to get it working every time.
>   I was using command line to check outgoing/incoming, do the phase
>   changes and such, but possibly never used it for the actual pull.
>
> Sorry to waste everybody's time. I resolved it as invalid, not sure if
>   someone wants to change it to a better category. Let me know if there
>   is anything else you want me to check or expand upon.

I'll edit in any updates, let me know if anyone is still having trouble with this.

Answer (score 1):

That seems like a bug. What version of Mercurial are you using? Have you tried filing a bug at https://bz.mercurial-scm.org ?

Comment: Local Version (multiple):
Mercurial - 2.1.1 up to 2.5.2
TortoiseHg - 2.3.1 up to 2.7.1
----
Remote Server Version
Mercurial - 2.4.2
TortoiseHg - 2.7