# How to keep changesets in phase “draft” on hg push?

Tags: mercurial, push, mercurial-phases

How can I hinder mercurial from putting changesets to phase “public” on push operations? I want them to stay “draft”.

I rebase and histedit a lot, and the repository I push to is for me only. And having to change the phase all the time is a nuisance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What the documentation does not clearly reveal is:

**The phase-change on push is not a purely local decision.** – After “uploading” the changesets, the client asks the server for updates regarding the phases of the commits, and the server is usually telling that they are now “public”.

Thus, the `.hgrc`-snippet

```
[phases]
publish = False
```

has to be put on the server, which inhibits the usual phase-change there. The server will then report the phases back the same way they were pushed.

Bitbucket has an option for this under *Settings → Repository details → Phases*.

Answer (score 4):

The most direct way to keep the phase at `draft` is to configure the remote server as "non-publishing", as you have already discovered.

But there is a second way, which may be useful to some if the destination server cannot be set to "non-publishing" for any reason: Use `pull` instead of `push`. Pulling is read-only, so if you can set up your workflow (e.g. through a local alias) so that the remote pulls changes from your local repo, they'll remain in phase `draft`.

Comment: you suggestion to use 'pull' worked for me. I tried the "non-publishing" setting listed above but it didn't work for me. Now my 'draft' stays that way on the server.

Comment: How do you push in such a way that the remote pulls from you?

Comment: You don't push, you ssh to the remote and pull from there. Interactively or with a script.

Comment: Most hosts which don’t let you edit the remote’s `.hg/hgrc` also don’t allow you an interactive shell or command other than `hg serve`. I thought there was maybe some trick to make `hg push` operate in pull mode, like how `hg clone` has both a hardlink mode and pull mode. Hmm, too bad.

Comment: Well yeah, you need to have some control over the destination server. My suggestion is useful if you don't _want_ to reconfigure the destination server, e.g. because it should behave as a publishing server except in this one case. (And by the way you know you can also use `hg phase -f --draft` to rewind the phase of some changesets to `draft`, right?)

Answer (score 2):

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Phases

```
A repository is "publishing" by default. To make a repository non-publishing, add these lines to its hgrc configuration:


[phases]
publish = False
```

Comment: Okay. Try to push second head, remove it later in local repo and push *this* change to remote!

Comment: @LazyBadger: For what?

Comment: @RobertSiemer - well, one of cases for "rewriting history" - I just found it by accident, when tested storm's easy way

Comment: @LazyBadger Yes, problematic.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: nohow

If you want rewrite history both locally and on push-target, you have to

- enable (on both sides)
- understand
- use [Evolve Extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/EvolveExtension) (still experimental)

Comment: I don’t want to rewrite on the push-target.

Comment: @RobertSiemer - you **want**, rewriting on *local only* doesn't have sense

Comment: Yeah, I do want to, but that is not part of the question.