# Edit .hgrc of repository on bitbucket

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket, hgrc, mercurial-phases

Is there a way to access and edit the .hgrc file of a Mercurial repository on Bitbucket? I am talking about the repository on Bitbucket itself, not a local clone of it.

The use case is that I would like to add the following in the .hgrc file

```
[phases]
publish = False
```

to mark the repository as non-publishing, as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810987/after-pushing-to-a-review-repository-abort-cant-rebase-immutable-changeset).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no way for doing that, but there is an issue reported to bitbucket so it may happen sometime in the future: [Provide a method for setting the phase of a repository to non-publishing.](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/4560/provide-a-method-for-setting-the-phase-of)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that under

*Settings → Repository details → Phases*

Comment: Yup, looks like they implemented the feature request mentioned in the other answer